# How to access k8s on another host from one linux machine

Tags: kubernetes

Now i did three things：
First, install kubectl on one linux machine,
Second, copy the admin.conf file from the remote k8s server to the ~/.kube/ file on the linux host,
Third, running kubectl get nodes under Linux reports an error. .

```
wanlei@kf-test:~/.kube$ kubectl get nodes
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I want to know what steps I have missed. .
The goal is to use kubectl from my linux host to manage k8s on the remote host

Answer (score 3):

You need to place the `kubeconfig` file at `.kube/config` location i.e there should be a file with name `config` at `.kube` directory.That's where `kubectl` looks for the `kubeconfig` file by default.

Alternative to above would be defining `KUBECONFIG` environment variable to point to a `kubeconfig` file in a different location.